# How to Insert data in Join table which were created by using EF Code First

Tags: linq, entity-framework, code-first

I have two Entity classes defined as

1) Project Class

```
public class Project
{
     [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }  
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }
}
```

2) Person Class

```
    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            Projects = new List<Project>();
        }


        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my DataContext Class, the configuration is defined as

```
  public class DataContext: DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base("name=DataContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Project>()
               .HasMany<Person>(p => p.Persons)
               .WithMany(p => p.Projects)
               .Map(m =>
               {
                   m.ToTable("ProjectPersons");
                   m.MapLeftKey("ProjectId");
                   m.MapRightKey("PersonId");
               });


        }

    }
```

After I created new project The project table and Person table populate with it's record but I notice ProjectPerson table which were created through joining not populated with the ProjectId And PersonId.

Any suggestion please?

Here is my HttpPost method to create new project

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult CreateProject(Projects newProject, int page = 1)
        {


            _ctx.Projects.AddProject(newProject, ref _ctx);
            _ctx.Person.AddPerson(newProject.Person, newProject, ref _ctx);

            _ctx.SaveChanges();

var userProjects = _ctx.Projects.GetStaffUserProjects(providerUserKey, page, ref _ctx);
                    return PartialView("_Projects", userProjects);

        }
```

And here are my Extension method which 'AddProject' and 'AddPerson'

1) AddProject

```
public static void AddProject(this IEnumerable<Project> projects, Projects newProject, ref DataContext ctx)
        {


               var project = new Project
                               {
                                   Title = newProject.Title,
                                   Duration = newProject.Duration,
                                   Description = newProject.Description,
                                   CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                                   Status = true,
                                   UserId = (int)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey,
                                   ProjectCategoryId = newProject.SelectedProjectCategoryId,
                                   OrganizationId = newProject.SelectedOrganizationId
                               };




            ctx.Projects.Add(project);
        }
```

2) AddPerson

```
public static void AddPerson(this IEnumerable<Person> persons, Person newPerson, Projects newProject, ref DataContext ctx)
        {



                   var person = new Person
                                   {
                                       Name = newPerson.Name,
                                       EmailAddress = newPerson.EmailAddress,
                                       CellPhone = newPerson.CellPhone,
                                       Designation = newPerson.Designation
                                   };



                ctx.Person.Add(person);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can someone please take a look at this post?

Comment: Can you show the code how you "*created new project*"?

Comment: Nobody reads your comment unless they look at your post :) - You probably never add items to either `Project.Persons` or `Person.Projects`. Anyway, as Slauma says, please show how you seed the database.

Comment: OK, where would you expect a `ProjectPerson` record to be created? You never tell EF which person belongs to which project. Off-topic: there are more issues with your code. The extension methods tie you to one-DbSet-each operations and the `IEnumerable` they apply to is never used! The `ref` keyword is - for what? `WebWideMediaDataContext` sounds like a global context, not context per request or per action method.

Comment: Please leave the off topic questions except "WebWideMediaDataContext". It was written by mistake, it actually 'DataContext'. I just need to know how can I tell EF which person belong to which project? As you know that I can not access 'ProjectPerson' through my DataContext class.

Comment: I mentioned this because it makes it hard to decide where to put the logic to connect persons and projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create the relationship between person and project you must add the project *that you have added or attached to the context* to the appropriate navigation collection. To do this (with minimal changes of your existing code) return the created project from `AddProject`:

```
public static Project AddProject(this IEnumerable<Project> projects,
    Projects newProject, ref DataContext ctx)
{
   var project = new Project { ... };
   ctx.Projects.Add(project);
   return project;
}
```

Then pass this returned project into `AddPerson`:

```
var project = _ctx.Projects.AddProject(newProject, ref _ctx);
_ctx.Person.AddPerson(newProject.Person, project, ref _ctx);
_ctx.SaveChanges();
```

And in `AddPerson` add it to the person's `Projects` collection:

```
public static void AddPerson(this IEnumerable<Person> persons, Person newPerson,
    Projects project, ref DataContext ctx)
{
    var person = new Person { ... };
    if (project != null)
        person.Projects.Add(project);
        // the preceding line tells EF about the relationship and will make it
        // generate an INSERT statement for the link table ProjectPerson
    ctx.Person.Add(person);
}
```